# Output results of SQL in function to R dataframe

Tags: sql, r, dataframe

I have a working R function that queries a server database and returns results as expected, however it simply prints the result to the console and I want to store the result as a dataframe object.

I have tried the code below

```
params <- function(
  BEG = '201801',
  END = '201802') {


  con <- dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), dsn = DSN)

   data <- odbc::dbSendQuery(con,  " SELECT A BUNCH OF DATA 
                      FROM some_tables where everything is what I want")

  odbc::dbBind(data, list(BEG, END))
  odbc::dbFetch(data) -> test
  er_vists <- as.data.frame(return(test))
}

params()
```

Everything works just fine, I just cant figure out how to save results to dataframe.  Does that need to happen outside of the function?  Any help or link to possible solutions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi as far as I can see your function works correctly.

Just modify the last line in your function save the output to a variable like this:

```
params <- function(BEG = '201801', END = '201802') {

  con <- dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), dsn = DSN)

  data <- odbc::dbSendQuery(con,  " SELECT A BUNCH OF DATA 
                            FROM some_tables where everything is what I want")

  odbc::dbBind(data, list(BEG, END))
  odbc::dbFetch(data) -> test
  return(as.data.frame(test))
}

mydata <- params()
mydata


mydata <- params()
```

Comment: works perfectly and exactly what I wanted.  Thanks for your help!